# Position Twitter Bootstrap framework topbar to stay at top of page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm playing around with Twitter's new CSS framework, [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

What I'm encountering is as follows: I've added the `topbar` div to my page:

```
<div class="topbar">
      <div class="fill">
        <div class="container">
          <h3><a href="#">Project Name</a></h3>
          <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
          <form action="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
          </form>
          <ul class="nav secondary-nav">
            <li class="menu">
              <a href="#" class="menu">Dropdown</a>
              <ul class="menu-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Secondary link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

However, this has some un-expected behavior: It proceeds to float down the page at the top - example [here](http://linode.jamesrgifford.com/example-twitter-bootstrap-topbar.html).

Is there a way to prevent that from happening, or do I need to consider a different framework?

Comment: I guess you haven't visited twitter.com in a while...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You mean the top bar is always to the top? That is the inteded behaviour.

You can change it by removing

```
position: fixed
```

in topbar's CSS definition.

Comment: I would recommend not editing the Twitter stylesheet, and creating your own stylesheet to override the twitter styles.

Comment: If you can avoid it don't edit it. If you can't, bootstrap-sass is great for editing some styles while keeping others the same.

Answer (score 11):

from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

To make the navbar fixed to the top of the viewport, add `.navbar-fixed-top` to the outermost div, `.navbar`. In your CSS, you will also need to account for the overlap it causes by adding `padding-top: 40px;` to your `<body>`.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="topbar">
  <div class="fill">
    <div class="container">
      <h3><a href="#">Project Name</a></h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
      </form>
      <ul class="nav secondary-nav">
        <li class="menu">
            <li class="dropdown" data-dropdown="dropdown" >
            <a href="#" class="menu">Dropdown</a>
              <ul class="menu-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Secondary link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```